# Prove a limsup and liminf inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, limsup-and-liminf

**Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a bounded sequence and let $B_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Prove that $\liminf a_n \le \liminf B_n \le \limsup B_n \le \limsup a_n$.**

*Please check whether the proof that i have mentioned below is correct or not.If there is a better or correct proof can you please show it here .*

Since $(a_n)$ is bounded, $\limsup a_n$ exists as a real number.
Let $L = \limsup a_n$ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $ε>0$.
Then $\exists K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $n>K$ , a_n < L+ε$.

Now let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Then

$a_{K+1} < L+ε$.

$a_{K+2} < L+ε$.

$\cdots$

$a_{K+n} < L+ε$.

Thus  $\frac{1}{n} ( a_{K+1} + a_{K+2} + \cdots + a_{K+n} ) < L+ε$.

Hence $\limsup \frac{1}{n} ( a_{K+1} + a_{K+2} + \cdots + a_{K+n} ) \le L+ε$.

Thus $\limsup \frac{1}{n} ( a_{1} + a_{2} + \cdots + a_{n} ) \le L$.

Comment: Please take a little time to look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to format your question nicely. You'll find that it's in fact much easier than using HTML as you have done. =)

Comment: Im having a difficulty in editing the post.Can you please be kind enough to take a moment to edit it if you dont mind. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, I'll edit it and after that you can click edit to see how it is done. Meanwhile you can think about the hint I'm giving in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Mention where i am going wrong in the proof that i have mentioned and whether i could use a different approach to correct it or not. :)

Comment: Can you provide the proof for this ?

Comment: Follow the hint in my answer. If you get stuck, edit your question to state whatever you have gotten.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is wrong because $\frac{1}{n} ( a_{K+1} + a_{K+2} + a_{K+3} + \cdots + a_{K+n} )$ is not an element of your sequence $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

**Hint**

Given any $ε > 0$, let $K$ be as you stated. Then as $n \to \infty$, we have $n > k$ and hence $B_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \frac{1}{n} ( \sum_{i=1}^K a_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^n a_i ) \le \cdots \text{[use the property of $K$ here]} \cdots \to \cdots$. Thus as $n \to \infty$ eventually $B_n < L+2ε$. Since this works for any such $ε$, we get $\limsup B_n \le L$.

Comment: Can you please mention whether i could proceed in the manner that i have started the proof or not.. And can you please share the correct proof.

Comment: can you explain how you got that Bn < L +2epsilon ? .

Comment: @Razor1692: As I said already, edit your question to show what you have tried by copying what I wrote and filling in the blanks. If you don't I cannot possibly know where your problem in understanding lies.